# GLIBC_2.29' not found help

Tags: python

i get this error when running an executable on linux and im not really sure how to update GLIBC without breaking my sistem

```
~~~[6057] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEILaGheb/libpython3.8.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /tmp/_MEILaGheb/libpython3.8.so.1.0)~~~
```